# Entire Range fills with only 1st item of array

Tags: arrays, excel, resize, range, vba

I have two arrays, both with rows=intAllNumsRows. The first array (arrAllNums) is Public Dim'd as Integer and is 6 columns wide, i.e. arrAllNums(1 to intAllNumsRows, 1 to 6). The second (arrAllNumsDates) is Public Dim'd as Date and is just 1 column wide, i.e. arrAllNumsDates(1 to intAllNumsRows). The dates correspond to their arrAllNums data.

As you can see in the code below, the Ranges are resized to rows equaling intAllNumsRows and their respective arrays are placed into them. The first Range and its array work just fine. The proper cells on the sheet have the data 6 columns wide and the correct number of rows. All the data shows.

The second Range is done exactly the same way with arrAllNumsDates, but only the first date...the date coming from arrAllNumsDates(1)...is placed in *all the cells of the range*. In other words, if arrAllNumsDates(1)=#1/1/2014#, then that is the date that is placed in every cell from AA5 through to the last cell row in the Range. The same date is in every cell.

As you can see, I've used Debug.Print to verify the actual dates stored in the array. They're perfect. There is nothing wrong with the array. And since Range does in fact display dates in all the correct cells, it seems that the Range is resizing properly. There is a date in all the proper cells. The confounding problem is that it is *the same date*, the first date in the array.

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("U5")
rng.Resize(intAllNumsRows, 6) = arrAllNums

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("AA5")
rng.Resize(intAllNumsRows, 1) = arrAllNumsDates

Set rng = Nothing


'**************************
Dim intI As Integer

For intI = 1 To intAllNumsRows
    Debug.Print arrAllNumsDates(intI)
Next

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-dimensional arrays are stored as rows - not columns. Just transpose your array and that should do the trick

```
rng.Resize(intAllNumsRows, 1) = worksheetfunction.transpose(arrAllNumsDates)
```

Edit: as a response to your comments below - in a first place, I think it may help to remember that an array and a range are two different things. An array is a particular data type that holds a number of data of a certain type. VBA just offers a convenient way to "look" at an array as if it was a range if you will. It can be helpful to think of an array in terms of a range, but then there are couple of subtleties in the way in which VBA actually sees an array as being a range that you need to consider.

One thing to consider is that the way in which VBA looks at an array as being a range depends on whether the array is one or two dimensional

- yourarray(1 to m, 1 to n): this will be seen as a range of m rows and n columns - as you would expect
- yourarray(1 to m): this will be seen as one row of m columns

Another subtlety is if you are trying to read a range into an array rather than the other way around - in this instance, a two dimensional array will always be returned, even if a single row or column is returned ie the array returned will involve an extra redundant dimension of 1 element.

Re the specific point where asking whether arrAllNums(intAllNums)=arrAllNums(1 to intAllNums, 1 to 1)

- arrAllNums(intAllNums) is a one dimensional array of intAllNums elements
- arrAllNums(1 to intAllNums, 1 to 1) is a two-dimensional array of intAllNums * 1 elements

Even though these two arrays can seem very similar and when it comes down to it in the second instance, the array is actually really a one-dimensional array with an extra redundant dimension, these are actually not the exact same things, and they are subtle differences in the underlying structure of these arrays that will lead VBA to look at them a bit differently

Hope this helps clarify

Comment: Okay, lemme just say going in that you're right...that fixed it. But in my mind I'm like a stammering little kid: "But...but...but..."

Comment: <p>Rats. I can't seem to hit 'enter' for new paragraphs. p-tags? I'll try.</p><p>Okay, lemme just say going in that you're right...that fixed it. So maybe I should just say thank you and walk away. But in my mind I'm like a stammering little kid: "But...but...but...". I've obviously got a conceptual issue going on here, and I'm trying to wrap my mind around it. </p>

Comment: Nope, not p-tags either. (sigh) Anyway, doesn't arrAllNums(intAllNums)=arrAllNums(1 to intAllNums, 1 to 1)? I do think of one-dimensional arrays as being *x* rows in a single column. I also think of rng.Resize(intAllNumsRows,1) as being *x* rows in a single column. So they seem dimensionally identical to me. Why do I have to transpose? What's more, the first array didn't have to be transposed; it worked just fine. So I'm not conceptualizing the difference? Anything you can say that might flip the light on for me?

Comment: IAmDranged, I very much appreciate your effort on my behalf. It is interesting to me that arr(x) is not identical to arr(x,1), so I will do some playing to examine the differences and impact. It still seems to me that rng(x,1) should be able to receive an array arr(x,1) without being transposed. While I understand that ranges are not identical to arrays, it seems like those two structures are the same. arr(x,1) is one column by x rows, and rng(x,1) is one column by x rows. I just don't get why I should have to transpose the array. Yes, it worked, but I'm not understanding why.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the Dim of the array from arr(1 to intAllNumsRows) to arr(1 to intAllNumsRows, 1 to 1). In doing so, the range now accepts the array directly and correctly *without* doing the transpose. I find this extremely odd, but obviously if I want to place single-dimensional arrays into a range I must *still* dimension the array in two dimensions, with the 2nd parameter being "1 to 1". While that clearly seems redundant, it obviously is not. But it makes a whole lot more sense to me to not have to transpose it.

Comment: I also just realized that that's what you were telling me when you said, "yourarray(1 to m): this will be seen as one row of m columns". I think my eyes/brain overlooked this because I *expected* that you said "one column of m rows". Now I realize that a single-dimensional array is one row of x columns. Now the reason to transpose makes sense, and why explicitly defining the array as arr(x, 1 to 1) resolves the problem. Thanks so much, IAmDranged.